# Does Everest contain a song that wasn't released at the time of the events depicted in the movie?

Tags: soundtrack, everest

In *Everest*, when they leave the Nepal airport and are sitting and chatting in a school bus sort of thing, the Hindi song [Yeh Ladka Hay Allah](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BE8_rNJOQ-0) from the movie [Kabhi Khushi Kabhi Gham](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0248126/) can be heard.

However, this movie was released in 2001, while *Everest* is based on the 1996 Everest disaster.

Comment: Given that Everest was an American production, I'm willing to bet that at least 99% of the crew members would never have even heard of that song, let alone known that hadn't been released at the time the film was set.

Comment: The song and movie were released long back in 2001 @F1Krazy

Comment: Is there even a question here? It seems to me you just wanted to post a possible error. That's not what this site is for.